# Is there any style guidelines about using implicit parameter with default value in scala?

Tags: scala, implicits

Is it fine to use such solutions like here:

```
def convert[T](x: T)(implicit format = Default) = ...
```

It allows you to not specify implicits if you don't need to. But many libraries (at least Lift Json and Scala Concurrent) avoid such kind of default implicit values and push user to always specify an implicit. Is there any recommendations about it for library designers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retronym said in passing:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/6MudBXELxVQ/ul67d5Rh4b4J

> Arguably it is in poor style to define implicit params with defaults

Compare:

[implicit parameter VS default parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479990/implicit-parameter-vs-default-parameter-value)

and here's a good one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016152/1296806

Comment: Full version of phrase "Arguably it is in poor style to define implicit params with defaults, but the results aren't that surprising IMO" :)

Comment: about last one - there is an possible option to solve the problem -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919012/1809978, but i haven't provided the code (and such macro required to be in separate jar so it's pretty much problematic to use).

Comment: isn't that a coincidence.